# Permissions for Symfony on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, acl

I worked with many Symfony projects before.
With my latest client I am having trouble to get the permissions right as required per Symfony:

```
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
```

The second command gives an error `setfacl: Option -m: Das Argument ist ungültig bei Zeichen 3`
 which roughly translates to `Option -m: the argument is invalid at character 3`

Was something changed and if so, where can I find informations about it?

The I am running Ubuntu 14.04. LTS on both machines.

//EDIT: I'm running a local git-server with Ubuntu 16.04. to deploy from dev to client, in case that matters...

Comment: 14.04. Sorry, wrong in title

Comment: This usually means that the user provided in the command does not exist. https://support.servergrove.com/error-setfacl-option-m-invalid-argument-near-character/

Comment: can you try `echo $HTTPDUSER` and see that it is being set?